# EF not updating related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following code:

```
var result = new koper_huurder
{
    guid = koperHuurder.Id.ToString(),
    persoon_1_guid = koperHuurder.KH1Id,
    persoon_2_guid = koperHuurder.KH2Id
};

Mapper.Map(koperHuurder, result);

result.persoon1 = new persoon
{
    guid = koperHuurder.KH1Id,
    mobiel = koperHuurder.KH1Mobiel,
    email_prive = koperHuurder.KH1EmailPrive,
    telefoon = koperHuurder.KH1TelefoonPrive
};

result.persoon2 = new persoon
{
    guid = koperHuurder.KH2Id,
    mobiel = koperHuurder.KH2Mobiel,
    email_prive = koperHuurder.KH2EmailPrive,
    telefoon = koperHuurder.KH2TelefoonPrive
};

context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, after `SaveChanges()`, nothing gets updated in the persoon table. It just updates the Koper_huurder table. I have checked this with SQL Server Profiler. Lazy Loading is disabled.

I don't know what to do!

EDIT

If I do the following, then I get validation error messages. It's telling me that certain columns in the persoon record can not be null. Which is odd, because I'm not doing anything with them.

```
--the same code as above and then--

context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(result.persoon1).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(result.persoon2).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `context.Entry(result).State` only marks scalar properties as modified, not navigation properties.

Comment: Alright. So what can I do to update the navigation properties?

Comment: First modify the state, then set the navigation properties. Because `result` is now first tracked by EF, it will notice the change in relationships.

Comment: I edited my question. But seeing your answer, this is not correct then.